# Select max using join not returning rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I'm stucked in this MYSQL SELECT:

```
SELECT episode.name
FROM tv.episode 
JOIN tv.show ON episode.show_id = show.id
WHERE show.id = 73545
AND season_number = 4
AND episode.number =(SELECT MAX(number) FROM tv.episode WHERE season_number = 4)
```

Returns 0 rows

The return from the second select is 22, so it works.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including `WHERE show.id = 73545` in your subquery with the `MAX`.

Comment: right, that was it... stupid me, must be the hours without sleeping. Thanks Ariel!